# Is the verbose version better or verboten?

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, data-binding, datasource

I've been populating a combobox this way (getRoundingMethodVals() returns a List`<String`>):

```
comboBoxRounding.DataSource = RateSetupData.getRoundingMethodVals();
```

...but I saw on a StackOverflow answer the following:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);
```

...which makes me wonder if I should change my code to:

```
comboBoxRounding.DataSource = new BindingSource(RateSetupData.getRoundingMethodVals(), null);
```

Is this a six-of-one-and-half-a-dozen-of-the-other situation? Or does one way hold a strong advantage over the other?

Comment: Should probably remove "verboten", which means "forbidden/prohibited" in German and fairly common in (my) English slang. In any case it detracts from the question.

Comment: @pst: Why? I know what it means - I speak German - and it fits my intent. Not that it's *literally* verboten/forbidden, of course, but you get my drift, I'm sure.

Comment: .. in which case it's [still] questionable in a title: try to avoid combative language and utilize the space to summarize the question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do.  If you just need to populate the comboBox for a user to select a value, then your first way works very well.  It's a one way data flow: from lsit to control.  In your case, a simple List(Of String) doesn't need a binding source.

However, if you have a much more complex object and want a change in the combobox value to also change the value of that object, you would use the BindingSource.  This creates a two-way data flow.  (For this scenario, you could use a BindingList which implements many of the BindingSource interfaces.)